# ASP.NET MVC: What goes where?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern

I am about to start developing a medium sized ASP.Net MVC application.
I am trying to get the design right. I intend to have the following layers:

- UI layer (MVC)
- Service Layer
- Repository Layer
- Data Access Layer

I will be using Unity as my IOC container and EF4.1 Code First for Data Access.

The app will be split into several assemblies. I have a problem deciding which assemblies I will need
and where to put the following:

- Entities/Domain objects e.g. Customer, Invoice
- DTOs e.g. CustomerDTO, InvoiceDTO
- Service interfaces e.g. ICustomerService
- Repository Interfaces e.g. ICustomerRepository
- Services(Service interface implementation classes) e.g. CustomerService
- Repositories (Repository Service implementation classes) e.g. CustomerRepository
- ViewModels e.g. CustomerViewModel
- Enums

My question is:
How do you usually split yours and why?

Edit: prompted by the @TheHurt's answer.

How would the references be between the assemblies, i.e. which assembly would be referencing which?

Comment: Do you need DTOs? Why can't you use the EFCF POCOs?

Comment: @TheHurt: I don't need DTOs for all the entities but for some, what the views need is very different from what is actually saved in the DB.

Comment: I think DTO's are still useful as sometimes you only want to pass a handful of properties about. I don't like to pass entities around that only have a couple of properties set (and everything else is set to default()) as it can be a bit dangerous.

Comment: DTOs are handy to encapsulate data between the controller and whatever type of layer you are using to handle your business logic. It clearly separates the controller from the application. You don't want to expose your entity's behaviour to the controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I might tackle it:

**App.UI assembly:**

- ViewModels go in Models area.

**App.Repository assembly:**

- Abstract implementation of concrete repository.
- ICustomerRepository

**App.Repository.SQL:**

- Concrete implementation.
- EFCF POCOs

**App.Services assembly:**

- Abstract service.
- ICustomerService
- DTOs

**App.Services.Implementation:**

- Concrete service.
- CustomerService

**App.Common:**

- Shared code.
- Enums

There are a couple issues that I still struggle with. You lose the data annotations from EFCF when you cross the services boundary. So then you have to do server side validation or you have to keep your view models validation in sync with the repository entities. It feels that the more layered things are, the more DRY is violated. I suppose that is par for the course though when your view models don't map to your entities directly. You could have your view models be your DTOs and toss them into the Common assembly, but that seems to couple things too tightly if you have the need to be super flexible with your services.

EDIT

If you are wanting to integrate WCF into the mix you would probably want to create data contracts that are very close to the MVC view model (or use the contracts as the view model). You probably wouldn't expose that to the world as the service would be specific to that implementation of your MVC site, spin up another service for public consumption. If you are doing a WCF service you probably want to have all of your business logic in the service, the controllers would just handle navigation logic.

Side note, I try to stay away from the "metal" as much as possible, while developing a design that will allow me to separate the code into various layers in the future. If I cannot clearly explain the various system layers to my manager with one sheet of paper, the design is more than likely too complex. Everything for the most part will look pretty in Visio if it is designed well.

As far as how things reference each other: UI would ref the Serivce (or service implementation, which may not be needed. Just keep it all in the same place.). Service refs the Repository. The repository implementation refs nothing, since it is loaded by IOC. Everything refs Common.

Comment: how do u differentiate b/w viewmodel and DTO and what about your Domain objects? do u add business logic to ur entities or what?

Comment: @TheHurt - Would you care to weigh in specifically on how you'd integrate WCF to the mix?

Comment: @TheHurt: Just a little clarification - Which assemblies would be referencing which in this case? See the edit in the question.

Comment: @Muhammad - The DTO represents your business entities, the view model is just what the view needs to render and submit, which may be a sub set of your DTO or a composition of multiple DTOs. DTOs are sort of a pain just because of all the object translation back and forth is prone to errors.

Comment: @TheHurt - Very helpful, TYVM

Comment: @TheHurt:  a point of correction - you actually don't loose the data annotations when you 'cross the service boundary' (I am interpreting this to mean 'use an entity in different assembly from the one it was declared in').